# Why do I have delays when pressing a keyboard key continuously to move the character?

Tags: movement, keyboard

What happens is I press right for a fraction of a second then release and my character moves to the right, as it is supposed to. I then press right again but this time for 5 seconds. My character moves immediately to the right and keeps moving with no pause between the first movement and the rest, as it is supposed to. But after 5 seconds of pressing right I then release the key and press left, but my character still keeps moving to the right for another 6 seconds. This effect is worse the longer I press the key. Why is that? I checked the boolean variables I am using to track the pressed and not pressed status of my keys and it seems like the status doesn't change until after the aforementioned 6 seconds during which the character keeps walking right although I am pressing left. However, key presses are still being detected quickly and on time in each iteration of the main game loop.

Based on my checks, key presses are still being checked quickly at each iteration of the main loop, and so is the key down/pressed status of keyboard keys. However, the key up/released status of keys is only checked until after the 6 seconds mentioned. Further checks showed that SDL2 poll event still reports a keydown status even though I am not pressing any keys and only reports a keyup after the 6 seconds. Is it windows 10 interfering with my program? It's like there's another program that keeps pressing right (same issue with other keys) eventhough I am no longer physically pressing that key.

I would appreciate your help and advice. Thank you.

I am programming in Free Pascal using SDL2. Below is a sample of my keyboard and other inputs procedure:

```
if sdl_pollevent(sdlevent)=1 then
begin
    { writeln(sdlevent^.type_,' ',sdl_keydown,' ',sdl_keyup); }
    if sdlevent^.type_=sdl_keydown then
    begin
        joystickactive:=false;
        { writeln(sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym); }
        { writeln(sdl_getkeyname(sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym)); }
        enterkeyintf:=false;
        if enterkeyintf=true then
        begin
            assign(t[1],'tf\tf0.tf');
            append(t[1]);
            settextbuf(t[1],bufin);
            writeln(t[1],sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym);
            writeln(t[1],sdl_getkeyname(sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym));
            close(t[1]);
        end;
        o[1]:=0;
        repeat
            o[1]:=o[1]+1;
            if sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym=keycode[o[1]] then keybool[o[1]]:=true;
        until o[1]=totalkeys;
        o[1]:=0;
        repeat
            o[1]:=o[1]+1;
            if sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym=alphanumm[o[1]] then alphanumbool[o[1]]:=true;
        until o[1]=totalalphanum;
    end;
    if sdlevent^.type_=sdl_keyup then
    begin
        joystickactive:=false;
        o[1]:=0;
        repeat
            o[1]:=o[1]+1;
            if sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym=keycode[o[1]] then keybool[o[1]]:=false;
        until o[1]=totalkeys;
        o[1]:=0;
        repeat
            o[1]:=o[1]+1;
            if sdlevent^.key.keysym.sym=alphanumm[o[1]] then alphanumbool[o[1]]:=false;
        until o[1]=totalalphanum;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is how I should my code on this forum. If it goes against the rules but here it is... This website won't let me press enter in this comment and won't let me delete it.

Comment: If you paste your code in the question, highlight and select the formatting option for code sample {} (next to the camera).

Comment: Sorry I can't find the button to edit my question nor the button to reply to your comment. The website doesn't show any of these buttons. Hence me adding this new comment. It's a bit confusing. Ok I found how to edit. It's written in tiny greyed out letters under my question, lol. Hard to spot or pay attention to.

Comment: So I did a few more checks. I checked the sequence of sdl event types when the keys are being pressed and released and sdl reports a type 768 for sdl_keydown (key pressed) and 769 for sdl_keyup (key released). However there is a type 771 that is detected by sdl after I press a key and keep pressing. What is sdl event type 771? This keeps being reported by sdl event type and is what I think is causing the character to keep walking right for another 6 seconds eventhough I am no longer pressing any key.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're iterating over keys after the event. It looks like you don't break when you find the key that triggered the event, and so are iterating over everything every time the event fires.

Comment: Stephan, what do you mean? You mean to exit the loop checking for keypresses and boolean definition as soon as I find the specific key being pressed? Or to not check the specific key again as long as it is being pressed? I did exit the loop as soon as the boolean is assigned to true but that does not fix the issue. The reason I do not exit the loop but iterate over all keys all the time is because I want to detect if the player is pressing more than one key.

Comment: I just tested exiting the loop as soon as keybool = true. The issue still persists.

Comment: I just fixed it! Compensated for that 771 event I don't want to have. I added the following line inside the poll event if block: if sdlevent^.type_=771 then sdl_pollevent(sdlevent); Not it works perfectly. The character is extremely responsive and no longer keeps walking.

Comment: Copy your answer out of the question, and post it as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Sorry for all the mistake in my typing but it's 1:19 in the morning here. I think what was happening is that SDL2 would pollevent once and not again if the key being pressed is still the same. If it's the same it would default to event type 771 (I couldn't find on the internet what that corresponds to). So I added the code to make the program run sdl_pollevent once more if it gets the code 771. Solved the problem.

Comment: I do know other systems I've used differentiate between onkeydown, onkeyup, and onkey events. It's possible the 771 is exactly as you suspect.

Comment: Yeah. It took me about 40 min to solve this problem I had never seen before. Ok, now I will go back to programming the map menu procedure for my game. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what was happening is that SDL2 would pollevent once and not again if the key being pressed is still the same. If it's the same it would default to event type 771 (I couldn't find on the internet what that corresponds to). So I added the code to make the program run sdl_pollevent once more if it gets the code 771. Solved the problem:

```
if sdl_pollevent(sdlevent)=1 then
begin
    if sdlevent^.type_=771 then sdl_pollevent(sdlevent);
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer as solved to close the question.

Comment: Thanks. I get a message saying I can accept it in two days.